# Ember-simple-auth cant get currentUser after reload

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have a simple Ember app ([repo](https://github.com/SimonBo/mini_booking_ember)) with authentication using ember-simple-auth (i followed this article https://medium.com/@benhansen/token-based-authentication-with-jwt-ember-and-rails-af54b03fe237). After logging in I have access to currentUser in my routes, controllers and templates. However, if I navigate to any route besides my ApplicationRoute and reload the browser, I can no longer access currentUser in that route, but it's available in the template. If I navigate back to application route and navigate to different one again, then I can access the currentUser. How can I fix this, i.e. I want to be able to access currentUser in any route even after reload?

ApplicationRoute:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  sessionAccount: Ember.inject.service(),
  beforeModel() {
    this.get('sessionAccount').loadCurrentUser();
  }
});
```

SessionAccount service:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { inject: { service }, RSVP } = Ember;

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  session: service('session'),
  store: service(),


  loadCurrentUser() {
    if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
      this.get('store')
      .queryRecord('user', { me: true })
      .then((user) => {
        this.set('currentUser', user);
      });
    } else {
      return RSVP.resolve();
    }
  }
});
```

Bookings route - the 'other' route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  sessionAccount: Ember.inject.service(),

  model() {
    const currentUser = this.get('sessionAccount.currentUser');

    return this.get('store').query('booking', {
      filter: {
        'user_id': currentUser.id
      },
      include: 'rental,rental.rental-ratings'
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended just following the [tutorial](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/guides/managing-current-user.md) form Ember simple auth github repo. Who would have thought this would work:) Had to change code in app/routes/application.js, also changed the name of my service from 'sessionAccount' to 'currentUser':

```
// app/routes/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

const { service } = Ember.inject;

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  currentUser: service(),

  beforeModel() {
    return this._loadCurrentUser();
  },

  sessionAuthenticated() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this._loadCurrentUser();
  },

  _loadCurrentUser() {
    return this.get('currentUser').load().catch(() => this.get('session').invalidate());
  }
});
```